¿Cómo cargar eficientemente grandes conjuntos de datos en memoria para entrenamiento de redes neuronales con PyTorch?
Estoy en el proceso de entrenar una red neuronal convolusional, usando Pytorch. Para esto, tengo diferentes archivos donde están los datos de entrenamiento, con un promedio de 40K datos datos en cada archivo y un total de 32 archivos. Los datos son arreglos bidimensionales que están codificados en enteros, pero para que entren en la red neuronal cada dato debe ser transformado en un tensor de tamaño 20x8x8 :
channels = 20
state = torch.zeros(
                channels, 8, 8, dtype=torch.float64
            )   

Para usar los datos, estoy heredando de la clase Dataset de torch.utils.data, para poder usarlo en un DataLoader. El problema que estoy teniendo, es que al almacenar los tensores (en un tensor más grande), está ocupando más memoria de lo que tenía planeado. Estoy pleando almacenar los datos en memoria sin transformarlos y convertirlos en tensores en demanda, pero siento que esto volvería lento el entrenamiento. ¿Habrá una forma más eficiente?
